# Text interpolation does not work inside ng-template

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass url adress inside my ng-template by text interpolation, but it does not work.

My html:

```
<ng-template #div2>
  <iframe
    width="560" 
    height="315"
    src="{{video}}"
    frameborder="0"
    webkitallowfullscreen
    allowfullscreen
    mozallowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</ng-template>
```

but what interesting if I pass URL by hard, it works:

```
<ng-template #div2>
  <iframe
    width="560" 
    height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BNcxTNrtRdk"
    frameborder="0"
    webkitallowfullscreen
    allowfullscreen
    mozallowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</ng-template>
```

in ts file video is declarde this way:

```
video = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/BNcxTNrtRdk';
```

How to fix it to make it possible to pass video url dynamically? It does not have to be text interpolation, I just do not want to have url hardcoded inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution, if someone  will need it.
In ts file:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}    
safeUrl;
     ngOnInit() {
        this.safeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/BNcxTNrtRdk');
      }
```

Then in html:

```
  <iframe
    [src]='safeUrl'
    frameborder="0"
    webkitallowfullscreen
    allowfullscreen
    mozallowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
```

Thats it! ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can define parameters with let.

```
<ng-template #template let-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BNcxTNrtRdk">
  <iframe
    width="560" 
    height="315"
    src="{{video}}"
    frameborder="0"
    webkitallowfullscreen
    allowfullscreen
    mozallowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</ng-template>
```

or with context:

```
   <div *ngFor='let video of videos'>
        <ng-container 
             [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" 
             [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{video:video}">
        </ng-container>
    </div>

<ng-template #template let-video="{{video}}">
  <iframe
    width="560" 
    height="315"
    src="{{video}}"
    frameborder="0"
    webkitallowfullscreen
    allowfullscreen
    mozallowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work for me. I got unsave url error or expected"{" token (no idea why), but i have found other solution - i have pasted it in another comment